# A system of linear (in)equalities

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces

I'm trying to figure out under what conditions on the data (i.e., $a$, $H$ and $G$) the following system has always a solution in $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$:

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
& a^\top \lambda_2 > \boldsymbol{1}^\top \lambda_1,\\
& H^\top \lambda_1 + G^\top \lambda_2 = 0,\\
& \lambda_1, \lambda_2 \geq 0,
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

where $\boldsymbol{1}$ is the vector of all elements equal to $1$, and the third set of inequalities holds element-wise.

For the first inequality, a necessary and sufficient condition should require that at least one element of $a$ is strictly greater than $0$, say $(a)_i > 0$. Then, for every $\lambda_1 \geq 0$, I can always find some $\lambda_2 \geq 0$ that makes the inequality satisfied (just putting a large value at the $i$-th entry of $\lambda_2$).

However, I also need to satisfy $H^\top \lambda_1 + G^\top \lambda_2 = 0$. In view of the consideration above on $\lambda_2$, is it true that this linear system has a solution if and only if $\textrm{span}(G^\top) \subseteq \textrm{span}(H^\top)$? Or perhaps $\textrm{coni}(-G^\top) \subseteq \textrm{coni}(H^\top)$, where $\textrm{coni}(\cdot)$ denotes the conic (positive) combination of the column space of its argument, thus accounting also for $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \geq 0$?